# iOS 7 - linkTextAttributes on UITextView works badly

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextview

As you can see on `UITextView` class, `linkTextAttributes` seems to be a new property available from iOS7:

```
// Style for links
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSDictionary *linkTextAttributes NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
```

and it should color links differently in an `UITextView` instance. So I tried to put a static (not editable) `UITextView` in a view controller (child of a tab bar controller), and set this property like below:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UITextView *copyrightText;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIColor *linkColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:202.0f/255.0f green:202.0f/255.0f blue:202.0f/255.0f alpha:1];
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:linkColor};
    self.copyrightText.linkTextAttributes = attributes;
}
```

but at first load, links color seems to be not set. Then, if I switch to another VC and return to current VC, links color changes. What's the problem with this code?

Comment: How and when do you set text of ``copyrightText`` instance?

Comment: From storyboard (it is a static non-editable UITextView)

Comment: Seems to be fixed on iOS 8..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this line of code. I'm always using this with the animation. I think it can help you achieve that view in first load.

------> [self.view layoutIfNeeded];